# Как закрыть новое окно в PyQt

Tags: python, pyqt5, gui, pyqt, qt-designer

Делаю небольшую *IDE* на *Python* с помощью *PyQt5*.

В меню есть кнопка `New File`, которая выполняет функцию создания нового файла. Когда я нажимаю на эту кнопку, то у меня выскакивает окно, где присутствует поле ввода названия нового файла и кнопка `Create`.

По идее, после того, как я нажал на кнопку `Create` у меня должно закрыться это новое окно. А оно не хочет закрываться, постоянно вылетает. Как это исправить?

Код снизу, прикрепил **3** файла, чтобы можно было воспроизвести пример.

Проблема в **1**-ом файле, где функция `new_file` и во **2**-ом файле, где функция `create_new_file`

Я пытался в функции `create_new_file` обращаться к `MainWindow` и закрывать `cfn_window`, то есть `MainWindow.cfn_window.hide()`, но это приводило к ошибке об импорте. Пытался обойти эту ошибку, но программа вылетала.

**Код 1-ого файла ide_window (главный файл):**

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtCore import QProcess
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from ide_ui import Ui_MainWindow
from create_new_file_window import Ui_CNFWindow
from pathlib import Path
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QFileDialog, QMessageBox


class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow, Ui_CNFWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setupUi(self)
        self.setWindowTitle("IDE")

        self.process = None

        self.code_entry_window.setDisabled(True)

        self.button_new_file.triggered.connect(self.new_file)
        self.button_open_file.triggered.connect(self.open_file)
        self.button_save_as.triggered.connect(self.save_as_file)
        self.button_run.triggered.connect(self.run_code)


    def message(self, string):
        self.result_of_program_execution_window.append(string)


    def run_code(self):
        if self.process is None:  # No process running.
            self.process = QProcess()
            self.process.readyReadStandardOutput.connect(self.handle_stdout)
            self.process.readyReadStandardError.connect(self.handle_stderr)
            self.process.finished.connect(self.finished_code)
            self.process.start("python", ['sandbox.py'])


    def handle_stderr(self):
        data = self.process.readAllStandardError()
        stderr = bytes(data).decode("utf8")
        self.message(stderr)


    def handle_stdout(self):
        data = self.process.readAllStandardOutput()
        stdout = bytes(data).decode("utf8")
        self.message(stdout)

    def finished_code(self):
        self.message("Process finished.")
        self.process = None

    def open_file(self):
        path = QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(self, "Save file", "",
                                           "All files (*.*)")[0]
        if path:
            try:
                with open(path, "r") as file:
                    self.code_entry_window.setPlainText(file.read())
            except Exception as e:
                QtWidgets.QErrorMessage().showMessage(str(e))

    def save_as_file(self):
        path = QFileDialog.getSaveFileName(self, "Open file", "",
                                           "All files (*.*)")[0]
        if path:
            try:
                with open(path, "w") as file:
                    text_on_current_file = self.code_entry_window.toPlainText()
                    file.write(text_on_current_file)
            except Exception as e:
                QtWidgets.QErrorMessage().showMessage(str(e))


    def new_file(self):
        # self.code_entry_window.setDisabled(False)
        # cfn_window.hide()
        self.cfn_window = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
        self.cfn_ui = Ui_CNFWindow()
        self.cfn_ui.setupUi(self.cfn_window)
        self.cfn_window.show()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    application = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    main_window = MainWindow()
    main_window.show()
    sys.exit(application.exec_())
```

**Код 2-ого файла create_new_file_window (окно, где создается файл):**

```
import inspect, os.path
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QFileDialog, QMessageBox


class Ui_CNFWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(584, 61)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.name_of_new_file_input_window = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.centralwidget)
        self.name_of_new_file_input_window.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 10, 471, 41))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(12)
        self.name_of_new_file_input_window.setFont(font)
        self.name_of_new_file_input_window.setObjectName("name_of_new_file_input_window")
        self.button_confirm_create_new_file = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.button_confirm_create_new_file.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(490, 10, 81, 41))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(10)

        # ------ ! ------
        self.button_confirm_create_new_file.setFont(font)
        self.button_confirm_create_new_file.setObjectName("button_confirm_create_new_file")
        self.button_confirm_create_new_file.clicked.connect(self.create_new_file)

        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "Create a new file"))
        self.button_confirm_create_new_file.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Create"))

    def create_new_file(self):
        filename = inspect.getframeinfo(inspect.currentframe()).filename
        path = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(filename))
        open(f"{path}\\{self.name_of_new_file_input_window.text()}.py",
             "a").close()
        successfully_msg = QMessageBox()
        successfully_msg.setWindowTitle("Create a new file")
        successfully_msg.setText("File created successfully")
        successfully_msg.setIcon(QMessageBox.Information)
        ex = successfully_msg.exec_()
```

**Код 3-его файла ide_ui где идет отрисовка главного окна (он нужен просто для воспроизведения примера, там, вроде, ошибок нет):**

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from create_new_file_window import Ui_CNFWindow
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt, QRect, QSize
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QWidget, QPlainTextEdit, QTextEdit
from PyQt5.QtGui import QColor, QPainter, QTextFormat


class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(605, 649)
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Segoe UI")
        font.setPointSize(9)
        font.setBold(False)
        font.setWeight(50)
        MainWindow.setFont(font)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        sizePolicy = QtWidgets.QSizePolicy(QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Maximum, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Preferred)
        sizePolicy.setHorizontalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setVerticalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setHeightForWidth(self.centralwidget.sizePolicy().hasHeightForWidth())
        self.centralwidget.setSizePolicy(sizePolicy)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.verticalLayout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self.centralwidget)
        self.verticalLayout.setObjectName("verticalLayout")
        self.code_entry_window = QCodeEditor(self.centralwidget)
        self.code_entry_window.setTabStopWidth(20)
        self.code_entry_window.setObjectName("code_entry_window")
        self.code_entry_window.setPlainText("Create a new file or open yours to get started")
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.code_entry_window)
        self.result_of_program_execution_window = QtWidgets.QTextBrowser(self.centralwidget)
        sizePolicy = QtWidgets.QSizePolicy(QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Minimum, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Minimum)
        sizePolicy.setHorizontalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setVerticalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setHeightForWidth(self.result_of_program_execution_window.sizePolicy().hasHeightForWidth())
        self.result_of_program_execution_window.setSizePolicy(sizePolicy)
        self.result_of_program_execution_window.setObjectName("result_of_program_execution_window")
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.result_of_program_execution_window)
        self.path_of_the_current_file_label_bottom = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.path_of_the_current_file_label_bottom.setObjectName("path_of_the_current_file_label_bottom")
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.path_of_the_current_file_label_bottom)
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.menubar = QtWidgets.QMenuBar(MainWindow)
        self.menubar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 605, 26))
        self.menubar.setObjectName("menubar")
        self.menu_file = QtWidgets.QMenu(self.menubar)
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Segoe UI")
        font.setBold(False)
        font.setWeight(50)
        self.menu_file.setFont(font)
        self.menu_file.setObjectName("menu_file")
        self.menu_edit = QtWidgets.QMenu(self.menubar)
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Segoe UI")
        font.setBold(False)
        font.setWeight(50)
        self.menu_edit.setFont(font)
        self.menu_edit.setObjectName("menu_edit")
        self.menu_run = QtWidgets.QMenu(self.menubar)
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Segoe UI")
        self.menu_run.setFont(font)
        self.menu_run.setObjectName("menu_run")
        MainWindow.setMenuBar(self.menubar)

        self.button_open_file = QtWidgets.QAction(MainWindow)
        self.button_open_file.setObjectName("button_open_file")

        self.actionOpen_Folder = QtWidgets.QAction(MainWindow)
        self.actionOpen_Folder.setObjectName("actionOpen_Folder")
        self.button_save = QtWidgets.QAction(MainWindow)
        self.button_save.setObjectName("button_save")
        self.button_save_as = QtWidgets.QAction(MainWindow)
        self.button_save_as.setObjectName("button_save_as")
        self.actionNew_Window = QtWidgets.QAction(MainWindow)
        self.actionNew_Window.setObjectName("actionNew_Window")
        self.button_new_window = QtWidgets.QAction(MainWindow)
        self.button_new_window.setObjectName("button_new_window")
        self.button_close_window = QtWidgets.QAction(MainWindow)
        self.button_close_window.setObjectName("button_close_window")
        self.actionClose_File = QtWidgets.QAction(MainWindow)
        self.actionClose_File.setObjectName("actionClose_File")
        self.actionClose_All_Files = QtWidgets.QAction(MainWindow)
        self.actionClose_All_Files.setObjectName("actionClose_All_Files")
        self.button_exit = QtWidgets.QAction(MainWindow)
        self.button_exit.setObjectName("button_exit")
        self.action_5 = QtWidgets.QAction(MainWindow)
        self.action_5.setObjectName("action_5")
        self.button_new_file = QtWidgets.QAction(MainWindow)
        self.button_new_file.setObjectName("button_new_file")
        self.button_undo = QtWidgets.QAction(MainWindow)
        self.button_undo.setObjectName("button_undo")
        self.button_redo = QtWidgets.QAction(MainWindow)
        self.button_redo.setObjectName("button_redo")
        self.actionFind_Ctrl_F = QtWidgets.QAction(MainWindow)
        self.actionFind_Ctrl_F.setObjectName("actionFind_Ctrl_F")
        self.actionReplace_Ctrl_H = QtWidgets.QAction(MainWindow)
        self.actionReplace_Ctrl_H.setObjectName("actionReplace_Ctrl_H")
        self.button_run = QtWidgets.QAction(MainWindow)
        self.button_run.setObjectName("button_run")
        self.button_cut = QtWidgets.QAction(MainWindow)
        self.button_cut.setObjectName("button_cut")
        self.button_copy = QtWidgets.QAction(MainWindow)
        self.button_copy.setObjectName("button_copy")
        self.button_paste = QtWidgets.QAction(MainWindow)
        self.button_paste.setObjectName("button_paste")
        self.button_stop = QtWidgets.QAction(MainWindow)
        self.button_stop.setObjectName("button_stop")
        self.actionSide_Bar = QtWidgets.QAction(MainWindow)
        self.actionSide_Bar.setObjectName("actionSide_Bar")
        self.action70 = QtWidgets.QAction(MainWindow)
        self.action70.setObjectName("action70")
        self.action79 = QtWidgets.QAction(MainWindow)
        self.action79.setObjectName("action79")
        self.action80 = QtWidgets.QAction(MainWindow)
        self.action80.setObjectName("action80")
        self.action100 = QtWidgets.QAction(MainWindow)
        self.action100.setObjectName("action100")
        self.action120 = QtWidgets.QAction(MainWindow)
        self.action120.setObjectName("action120")
        self.menu_file.addAction(self.button_new_file)
        self.menu_file.addAction(self.button_open_file)
        self.menu_file.addAction(self.button_save)
        self.menu_file.addAction(self.button_save_as)
        self.menu_file.addSeparator()
        self.menu_file.addAction(self.button_new_window)
        self.menu_file.addAction(self.button_close_window)
        self.menu_file.addSeparator()
        self.menu_file.addAction(self.button_exit)
        self.menu_edit.addAction(self.button_undo)
        self.menu_edit.addAction(self.button_redo)
        self.menu_edit.addSeparator()
        self.menu_edit.addAction(self.button_cut)
        self.menu_edit.addAction(self.button_copy)
        self.menu_edit.addAction(self.button_paste)
        self.menu_run.addAction(self.button_run)
        self.menu_run.addAction(self.button_stop)
        self.menubar.addAction(self.menu_file.menuAction())
        self.menubar.addAction(self.menu_edit.menuAction())
        self.menubar.addAction(self.menu_run.menuAction())

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
        self.path_of_the_current_file_label_bottom.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "C:Windows\\System32\\PyCharmProjects\\Examples\\sandbox.py"))
        self.menu_file.setTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "File"))
        self.menu_edit.setTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "Edit"))
        self.menu_run.setTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "Run"))
        self.button_open_file.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Open File..."))
        self.actionOpen_Folder.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Open Folder..."))
        self.button_save.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Save"))
        self.button_save_as.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Save As..."))
        self.actionNew_Window.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "New Window..."))
        self.button_new_window.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "New Window"))
        self.button_close_window.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Close Window"))
        self.actionClose_File.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Close File"))
        self.actionClose_All_Files.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Close All Files"))
        self.button_exit.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Exit"))
        self.action_5.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Ctrl + N"))
        self.button_new_file.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "New File"))
        self.button_undo.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Undo                           Ctrl+Z"))
        self.button_redo.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Redo                            Ctrl+Y"))
        self.actionFind_Ctrl_F.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Find..."))
        self.actionReplace_Ctrl_H.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Replace..."))
        self.button_run.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Run                              Ctrl+Shift+B"))
        self.button_cut.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Cut                               Ctrl+X"))
        self.button_copy.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Copy                            Ctrl+C"))
        self.button_paste.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Paste                            Ctrl+V"))
        self.button_stop.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Stop                             Ctrl+Q"))
        self.actionSide_Bar.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Hide Side Bar                               Ctrl+K"))
        self.action70.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "70"))
        self.action79.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "79"))
        self.action80.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "80"))
        self.action100.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "100"))
        self.action120.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "120"))

# ------------------------------------------------------------------------

class QLineNumberArea(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, editor):
        super().__init__(editor)
        self.codeEditor = editor

    def sizeHint(self):
        return QSize(self.editor.lineNumberAreaWidth(), 0)

    def paintEvent(self, event):
        self.codeEditor.lineNumberAreaPaintEvent(event)


class QCodeEditor(QPlainTextEdit):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.lineNumberArea = QLineNumberArea(self)
        self.blockCountChanged.connect(self.updateLineNumberAreaWidth)
        self.updateRequest.connect(self.updateLineNumberArea)
        self.cursorPositionChanged.connect(self.highlightCurrentLine)
        self.updateLineNumberAreaWidth(0)

    def lineNumberAreaWidth(self):
        digits = 1
        max_value = max(1, self.blockCount())
        while max_value >= 10:
            max_value /= 10
            digits += 1
        space = 3 + self.fontMetrics().width('9') * digits
        return space

    def updateLineNumberAreaWidth(self, _):
        self.setViewportMargins(self.lineNumberAreaWidth(), 0, 0, 0)

    def updateLineNumberArea(self, rect, dy):
        if dy:
            self.lineNumberArea.scroll(0, dy)
        else:
            self.lineNumberArea.update(0, rect.y(), self.lineNumberArea.width(), rect.height())
        if rect.contains(self.viewport().rect()):
            self.updateLineNumberAreaWidth(0)

    def resizeEvent(self, event):
        super().resizeEvent(event)
        cr = self.contentsRect()
        self.lineNumberArea.setGeometry(QRect(cr.left(), cr.top(), self.lineNumberAreaWidth(), cr.height()))

    def highlightCurrentLine(self):
        extraSelections = []
        if not self.isReadOnly():
            selection = QTextEdit.ExtraSelection()
            lineColor = QColor(Qt.yellow).lighter(160)
            selection.format.setBackground(lineColor)
            selection.format.setProperty(QTextFormat.FullWidthSelection, True)
            selection.cursor = self.textCursor()
            selection.cursor.clearSelection()
            extraSelections.append(selection)
        self.setExtraSelections(extraSelections)

    def lineNumberAreaPaintEvent(self, event):
        painter = QPainter(self.lineNumberArea)

        painter.fillRect(event.rect(), Qt.lightGray)

        block = self.firstVisibleBlock()
        blockNumber = block.blockNumber()
        top = self.blockBoundingGeometry(block).translated(self.contentOffset()).top()
        bottom = top + self.blockBoundingRect(block).height()

        # Just to make sure I use the right font
        height = self.fontMetrics().height()
        while block.isValid() and (top <= event.rect().bottom()):
            if block.isVisible() and (bottom >= event.rect().top()):
                number = str(blockNumber + 1)
                painter.setPen(Qt.black)
                painter.drawText(0, top, self.lineNumberArea.width(), height, Qt.AlignRight, number)

            block = block.next()
            top = bottom
            bottom = top + self.blockBoundingRect(block).height()
            blockNumber += 1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Не изменяйте код, сгенерированный *Qt Designer*. Создайте другой класс,
который наследуется от соответствующего виджета, и используйте созданный класс для его заполнения.

**maim.py**

```
import sys
import inspect
import os.path
from pathlib import Path
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.Qt import *

from create_new_file_window import Ui_CNFWindow
from ide_ui import Ui_MainWindow


# +++ vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv  !!!
class CnfWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, Ui_CNFWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setupUi(self)
        self.setWindowTitle("CNFWindow")   

        self.button_confirm_create_new_file.clicked.connect(self.create_new_file)

    def create_new_file(self):
        filename = inspect.getframeinfo(inspect.currentframe()).filename
        path = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(filename))
        
        open(f"{path}\\{self.name_of_new_file_input_window.text()}.py",
             "a").close()
             
        successfully_msg = QMessageBox()
        successfully_msg.setWindowTitle("Create a new file")
        successfully_msg.setText("File created successfully")
        successfully_msg.setIcon(QMessageBox.Information)
        ex = successfully_msg.exec_()
        self.hide()                                                              # <---
# +++ ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^        


#class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow, Ui_CNFWindow):           # - НЕТ
class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):                          # + ДА !!!
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setupUi(self)
        self.setWindowTitle("IDE")

        self.process = None
        self.code_entry_window.setDisabled(True)

        self.button_new_file.triggered.connect(self.new_file)
        self.button_open_file.triggered.connect(self.open_file)
        self.button_save_as.triggered.connect(self.save_as_file)
        self.button_run.triggered.connect(self.run_code)
        
        self.cfn_window = CnfWindow()                                             # +++ !!!

    def message(self, string):
        self.result_of_program_execution_window.append(string)

    def run_code(self):
        if self.process is None:  # No process running.
            self.process = QProcess()
            self.process.readyReadStandardOutput.connect(self.handle_stdout)
            self.process.readyReadStandardError.connect(self.handle_stderr)
            self.process.finished.connect(self.finished_code)
            self.process.start("python", ['sandbox.py'])

    def handle_stderr(self):
        data = self.process.readAllStandardError()
        stderr = bytes(data).decode("utf8")
        self.message(stderr)

    def handle_stdout(self):
        data = self.process.readAllStandardOutput()
        stdout = bytes(data).decode("utf8")
        self.message(stdout)

    def finished_code(self):
        self.message("Process finished.")
        self.process = None

    def open_file(self):
        path = QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(self, "Save file", "",
                                           "All files (*.*)")[0]
        if path:
            try:
                with open(path, "r") as file:
                    self.code_entry_window.setPlainText(file.read())
            except Exception as e:
                QtWidgets.QErrorMessage().showMessage(str(e))

    def save_as_file(self):
        path = QFileDialog.getSaveFileName(self, "Open file", "",
                                           "All files (*.*)")[0]
        if path:
            try:
                with open(path, "w") as file:
                    text_on_current_file = self.code_entry_window.toPlainText()
                    file.write(text_on_current_file)
            except Exception as e:
                QtWidgets.QErrorMessage().showMessage(str(e))

    def new_file(self):
        # self.code_entry_window.setDisabled(False)
        # cfn_window.hide()
#        self.cfn_window = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
#        self.cfn_ui = Ui_CNFWindow()
#        self.cfn_ui.setupUi(self.cfn_window)
        
        self.cfn_window.name_of_new_file_input_window.clear()                    # +++
        self.cfn_window.show()                                                   # +++


if __name__ == "__main__":
    application = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    main_window = MainWindow()
    main_window.show()
    sys.exit(application.exec_())
```

**ide_ui.py**

```
# WARNING! All changes made in this file will be lost!

from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.Qt import *


class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(605, 649)
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Segoe UI")
        font.setPointSize(9)
        font.setBold(False)
        font.setWeight(50)
        MainWindow.setFont(font)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        sizePolicy = QtWidgets.QSizePolicy(QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Maximum, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Preferred)
        sizePolicy.setHorizontalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setVerticalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setHeightForWidth(self.centralwidget.sizePolicy().hasHeightForWidth())
        self.centralwidget.setSizePolicy(sizePolicy)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.verticalLayout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self.centralwidget)
        self.verticalLayout.setObjectName("verticalLayout")
        self.code_entry_window = QCodeEditor(self.centralwidget)
        self.code_entry_window.setTabStopWidth(20)
        self.code_entry_window.setObjectName("code_entry_window")
        self.code_entry_window.setPlainText("Create a new file or open yours to get started")
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.code_entry_window)
        self.result_of_program_execution_window = QtWidgets.QTextBrowser(self.centralwidget)
        sizePolicy = QtWidgets.QSizePolicy(QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Minimum, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Minimum)
        sizePolicy.setHorizontalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setVerticalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setHeightForWidth(self.result_of_program_execution_window.sizePolicy().hasHeightForWidth())
        self.result_of_program_execution_window.setSizePolicy(sizePolicy)
        self.result_of_program_execution_window.setObjectName("result_of_program_execution_window")
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.result_of_program_execution_window)
        self.path_of_the_current_file_label_bottom = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.path_of_the_current_file_label_bottom.setObjectName("path_of_the_current_file_label_bottom")
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.path_of_the_current_file_label_bottom)
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.menubar = QtWidgets.QMenuBar(MainWindow)
        self.menubar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 605, 26))
        self.menubar.setObjectName("menubar")
        self.menu_file = QtWidgets.QMenu(self.menubar)
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Segoe UI")
        font.setBold(False)
        font.setWeight(50)
        self.menu_file.setFont(font)
        self.menu_file.setObjectName("menu_file")
        self.menu_edit = QtWidgets.QMenu(self.menubar)
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Segoe UI")
        font.setBold(False)
        font.setWeight(50)
        self.menu_edit.setFont(font)
        self.menu_edit.setObjectName("menu_edit")
        self.menu_run = QtWidgets.QMenu(self.menubar)
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Segoe UI")
        self.menu_run.setFont(font)
        self.menu_run.setObjectName("menu_run")
        MainWindow.setMenuBar(self.menubar)

        self.button_open_file = QtWidgets.QAction(MainWindow)
        self.button_open_file.setObjectName("button_open_file")

        self.actionOpen_Folder = QtWidgets.QAction(MainWindow)
        self.actionOpen_Folder.setObjectName("actionOpen_Folder")
        self.button_save = QtWidgets.QAction(MainWindow)
        self.button_save.setObjectName("button_save")
        self.button_save_as = QtWidgets.QAction(MainWindow)
        self.button_save_as.setObjectName("button_save_as")
        self.actionNew_Window = QtWidgets.QAction(MainWindow)
        self.actionNew_Window.setObjectName("actionNew_Window")
        self.button_new_window = QtWidgets.QAction(MainWindow)
        self.button_new_window.setObjectName("button_new_window")
        self.button_close_window = QtWidgets.QAction(MainWindow)
        self.button_close_window.setObjectName("button_close_window")
        self.actionClose_File = QtWidgets.QAction(MainWindow)
        self.actionClose_File.setObjectName("actionClose_File")
        self.actionClose_All_Files = QtWidgets.QAction(MainWindow)
        self.actionClose_All_Files.setObjectName("actionClose_All_Files")
        self.button_exit = QtWidgets.QAction(MainWindow)
        self.button_exit.setObjectName("button_exit")
        self.action_5 = QtWidgets.QAction(MainWindow)
        self.action_5.setObjectName("action_5")
        self.button_new_file = QtWidgets.QAction(MainWindow)
        self.button_new_file.setObjectName("button_new_file")
        self.button_undo = QtWidgets.QAction(MainWindow)
        self.button_undo.setObjectName("button_undo")
        self.button_redo = QtWidgets.QAction(MainWindow)
        self.button_redo.setObjectName("button_redo")
        self.actionFind_Ctrl_F = QtWidgets.QAction(MainWindow)
        self.actionFind_Ctrl_F.setObjectName("actionFind_Ctrl_F")
        self.actionReplace_Ctrl_H = QtWidgets.QAction(MainWindow)
        self.actionReplace_Ctrl_H.setObjectName("actionReplace_Ctrl_H")
        self.button_run = QtWidgets.QAction(MainWindow)
        self.button_run.setObjectName("button_run")
        self.button_cut = QtWidgets.QAction(MainWindow)
        self.button_cut.setObjectName("button_cut")
        self.button_copy = QtWidgets.QAction(MainWindow)
        self.button_copy.setObjectName("button_copy")
        self.button_paste = QtWidgets.QAction(MainWindow)
        self.button_paste.setObjectName("button_paste")
        self.button_stop = QtWidgets.QAction(MainWindow)
        self.button_stop.setObjectName("button_stop")
        self.actionSide_Bar = QtWidgets.QAction(MainWindow)
        self.actionSide_Bar.setObjectName("actionSide_Bar")
        self.action70 = QtWidgets.QAction(MainWindow)
        self.action70.setObjectName("action70")
        self.action79 = QtWidgets.QAction(MainWindow)
        self.action79.setObjectName("action79")
        self.action80 = QtWidgets.QAction(MainWindow)
        self.action80.setObjectName("action80")
        self.action100 = QtWidgets.QAction(MainWindow)
        self.action100.setObjectName("action100")
        self.action120 = QtWidgets.QAction(MainWindow)
        self.action120.setObjectName("action120")
        self.menu_file.addAction(self.button_new_file)
        self.menu_file.addAction(self.button_open_file)
        self.menu_file.addAction(self.button_save)
        self.menu_file.addAction(self.button_save_as)
        self.menu_file.addSeparator()
        self.menu_file.addAction(self.button_new_window)
        self.menu_file.addAction(self.button_close_window)
        self.menu_file.addSeparator()
        self.menu_file.addAction(self.button_exit)
        self.menu_edit.addAction(self.button_undo)
        self.menu_edit.addAction(self.button_redo)
        self.menu_edit.addSeparator()
        self.menu_edit.addAction(self.button_cut)
        self.menu_edit.addAction(self.button_copy)
        self.menu_edit.addAction(self.button_paste)
        self.menu_run.addAction(self.button_run)
        self.menu_run.addAction(self.button_stop)
        self.menubar.addAction(self.menu_file.menuAction())
        self.menubar.addAction(self.menu_edit.menuAction())
        self.menubar.addAction(self.menu_run.menuAction())

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
        self.path_of_the_current_file_label_bottom.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "C:Windows\\System32\\PyCharmProjects\\Examples\\sandbox.py"))
        self.menu_file.setTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "File"))
        self.menu_edit.setTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "Edit"))
        self.menu_run.setTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "Run"))
        self.button_open_file.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Open File..."))
        self.actionOpen_Folder.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Open Folder..."))
        self.button_save.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Save"))
        self.button_save_as.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Save As..."))
        self.actionNew_Window.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "New Window..."))
        self.button_new_window.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "New Window"))
        self.button_close_window.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Close Window"))
        self.actionClose_File.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Close File"))
        self.actionClose_All_Files.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Close All Files"))
        self.button_exit.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Exit"))
        self.action_5.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Ctrl + N"))
        self.button_new_file.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "New File"))
        self.button_undo.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Undo                           Ctrl+Z"))
        self.button_redo.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Redo                            Ctrl+Y"))
        self.actionFind_Ctrl_F.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Find..."))
        self.actionReplace_Ctrl_H.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Replace..."))
        self.button_run.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Run                              Ctrl+Shift+B"))
        self.button_cut.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Cut                               Ctrl+X"))
        self.button_copy.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Copy                            Ctrl+C"))
        self.button_paste.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Paste                            Ctrl+V"))
        self.button_stop.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Stop                             Ctrl+Q"))
        self.actionSide_Bar.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Hide Side Bar                               Ctrl+K"))
        self.action70.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "70"))
        self.action79.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "79"))
        self.action80.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "80"))
        self.action100.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "100"))
        self.action120.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "120"))


# ------------------------------------------------------------------------

class QLineNumberArea(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, editor):
        super().__init__(editor)
        self.codeEditor = editor

    def sizeHint(self):
        return QSize(self.editor.lineNumberAreaWidth(), 0)

    def paintEvent(self, event):
        self.codeEditor.lineNumberAreaPaintEvent(event)


class QCodeEditor(QPlainTextEdit):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.lineNumberArea = QLineNumberArea(self)
        self.blockCountChanged.connect(self.updateLineNumberAreaWidth)
        self.updateRequest.connect(self.updateLineNumberArea)
        self.cursorPositionChanged.connect(self.highlightCurrentLine)
        self.updateLineNumberAreaWidth(0)

    def lineNumberAreaWidth(self):
        digits = 1
        max_value = max(1, self.blockCount())
        while max_value >= 10:
            max_value /= 10
            digits += 1
        space = 3 + self.fontMetrics().width('9') * digits
        return space

    def updateLineNumberAreaWidth(self, _):
        self.setViewportMargins(self.lineNumberAreaWidth(), 0, 0, 0)

    def updateLineNumberArea(self, rect, dy):
        if dy:
            self.lineNumberArea.scroll(0, dy)
        else:
            self.lineNumberArea.update(0, rect.y(), self.lineNumberArea.width(), rect.height())
        if rect.contains(self.viewport().rect()):
            self.updateLineNumberAreaWidth(0)

    def resizeEvent(self, event):
        super().resizeEvent(event)
        cr = self.contentsRect()
        self.lineNumberArea.setGeometry(QRect(cr.left(), cr.top(), self.lineNumberAreaWidth(), cr.height()))

    def highlightCurrentLine(self):
        extraSelections = []
        if not self.isReadOnly():
            selection = QTextEdit.ExtraSelection()
            lineColor = QColor(Qt.yellow).lighter(160)
            selection.format.setBackground(lineColor)
            selection.format.setProperty(QTextFormat.FullWidthSelection, True)
            selection.cursor = self.textCursor()
            selection.cursor.clearSelection()
            extraSelections.append(selection)
        self.setExtraSelections(extraSelections)

    def lineNumberAreaPaintEvent(self, event):
        painter = QPainter(self.lineNumberArea)

        painter.fillRect(event.rect(), Qt.lightGray)

        block = self.firstVisibleBlock()
        blockNumber = block.blockNumber()
        top = self.blockBoundingGeometry(block).translated(self.contentOffset()).top()
        bottom = top + self.blockBoundingRect(block).height()

        # Just to make sure I use the right font
        height = self.fontMetrics().height()
        while block.isValid() and (top <= event.rect().bottom()):
            if block.isVisible() and (bottom >= event.rect().top()):
                number = str(blockNumber + 1)
                painter.setPen(Qt.black)
                painter.drawText(0, top, self.lineNumberArea.width(), height, Qt.AlignRight, number)

            block = block.next()
            top = bottom
            bottom = top + self.blockBoundingRect(block).height()
            blockNumber += 1
```

**create_new_file_window.py**

```
# WARNING! All changes made in this file will be lost!

from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets

class Ui_CNFWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(584, 61)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.name_of_new_file_input_window = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.centralwidget)
        self.name_of_new_file_input_window.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 10, 471, 41))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(12)
        self.name_of_new_file_input_window.setFont(font)
        self.name_of_new_file_input_window.setObjectName("name_of_new_file_input_window")
        self.button_confirm_create_new_file = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.button_confirm_create_new_file.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(490, 10, 81, 41))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(10)

        # ------ ! ------
        self.button_confirm_create_new_file.setFont(font)
        self.button_confirm_create_new_file.setObjectName("button_confirm_create_new_file")
        
# WARNING! All changes made in this file will be lost!
#        self.button_confirm_create_new_file.clicked.connect(self.create_new_file)

        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)


    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "Create a new file"))
        self.button_confirm_create_new_file.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Create"))

# WARNING! All changes made in this file will be lost! 
'''
    def create_new_file(self):
        filename = inspect.getframeinfo(inspect.currentframe()).filename
        path = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(filename))
        print(f'filename = {filename}')
        print(f'path     = {path}')
        
        open(f"{path}\\{self.name_of_new_file_input_window.text()}.py",
             "a").close()
             
        successfully_msg = QMessageBox()
        successfully_msg.setWindowTitle("Create a new file")
        successfully_msg.setText("File created successfully")
        successfully_msg.setIcon(QMessageBox.Information)
        ex = successfully_msg.exec_()
'''
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Вы ангел-хранитель темы PyQt. Благодарю сердечно :)